# Remove element from list - JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, element

I have a list like this in a div:

```
<div id="x">5,2,3,1,4,9,8</div>
```

How do I simply remove a given element from this list?
JQuery or JavaScript may be used.

Please note that the numbers in the list are unique and they are coming in from a database of type int(11), they are not in any sort of order.

Any help appreciated guys...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get the text:

```
var text=$("#x").text();
```

Then split it:

```
var items=text.split(',');
```

If there's no items, you'll have an empty string as the only element of the array. If so, empty the array:

```
if(items.length==1&&items[0]=="") {
    items=[];
}
```

Now convert everything to an integer: (note that this step isn't actually required, but if you're doing anything else with `items`, it's nice to have)

```
items=items.map(function(str) { return parseInt(str, 10); });
```

Put the item you want to remove in a variable:

```
var itemToRemove=3;
```

Find that in the array:

```
var index=items.indexOf(itemToRemove);
```

If it was found, splice it out of the array:

```
if(index!==-1) {
    items.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Join the items back together:

```
text=items.join(',');
```

Put it back in the element:

```
$("#x").text(text);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this with `toRemove` equal to 5, 3, or 8 to see that it works for all cases:

```
var toRemove = 3; // the number you want to remove
$('#x').text($('#x').text().replace(new RegExp(toRemove + ',?'
                                               + '|,?' + toRemove + '$'), ''));
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/6N9w9/)

Comment: +1, but your regex is bad.  It'll match things like `33,`.  Use `new RegExp('[^,]' + toRemove + '(?=[$,])')`

Comment: You're right, my apologies.  If you answer I will delete mine and +1 you.

Comment: Actually, just realized the regex I posted won't quite work.  Yours is actually closer to what's needed :)  `new RegExp('(^|,)' + toRemove + ',|,' + toRemove + '$')` and replace with `$1`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution that just requires jquery.

```
function removeFromDiv(which)
{
    var data = $("#x").html();
    data_arr = data.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < data_arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (data_arr[i] == which)
        {
            data_arr.splice(i, 1);
            data = data_arr.join(",");
        }
    }
    $("#x").html(data);
}
```

then simply run:

```
removeFromDiv("4");
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `for...in` on arrays; if someone has extended `Array.prototype` it will iterate over those properties as well.

Comment: Interesting, what's the solution to iterating over an array then?

Comment: @two13: Either call `forEach` on the array if you're not modifying it (note that `forEach` is not supported by some older browsers, however), or use `for(var i=0, l=myArray.length; i<l; i++)`.

Comment: @two13: Oh, I forgot one other thing. You'll have to decrement `l` when you remove an element if you're using that cache-length thing. Alternatively, to not cache the length, you could use this: `for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)`

Comment: @icktoofay both versions work identical in my tests.  It doesn't appear to affect the array length after it's removed and still steps through the array properly regardless of which version I use.  Is there some instance where one of them would break? *edit* nevermind I see it throws an error with first version because the array is too long, gotcha, will update. :)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't really need to be much harder than this:

```
function removeIndexFromX(index) {
  // Build array from comma-delimited content
  var arr = $("#x").text().split(',');

  // Remove index (zero-based)
  arr.splice(index, 1);

  // Replace
  $("#x").text(arr.join(','));
}

function removeNumberFromX(num) {
  var arr = $("#x").text().split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === num) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  $("#x").text(arr.join(','));
}
```

The benefit of `split` and `join` is that you can use those to manage delimiters (e.g. commas) for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's grep-method may be an option too:

```
var toRemove=1; 
$('#x').text( $.grep($('#x').text().split(','),
                     function (a) { return a != toRemove; }).join(','));
```

To remove multiple items:

```
var toRemove=[1,8,3]; 
$('#x').text( $.grep($('#x').text().split(','),
                     function (a) { return $.inArray(Number(a),toRemove)<0; })
                       .join(','));
```

(But I would prefer a RegExp-solution, it should be much faster)