# Jquery - how to remove element that is not inside a div

Tags: jquery

Hi I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="screenlist">
www.sampleurl.com</br>
www.sampleurl.com</br>
www.sampleurl.com</br>
www.sampleurl.com</br>
www.sampleurl.com</br>
www.sampleurl.com</br>
 </div>
```

I have a button that appends a URL in that list:

```
 $('#screenlist').append(url + '</br>');
```

Now I would like to add an "X" in order to delete any of the links.

```
 $('#screenlist').append(url + ' <span class="delete_icon" /></br>');
```

> How can I attach a click event to that span element that will be dynamic on every element created and that when clicked the complete row is deleted?

Any clue?

Comment: `$(document).on('click','.delete_icon',function(){//code here})` read on [devent delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for further  info

Comment: is there any reason why you don't want each item inside a list?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane no there is no reason. The thing is that I have a filter to get those elements into an array: var contents = $('#screenlist').html().split(/\n|\<br>/).filter(function(v) {
                            return /\w+/.test(v);
                        });

Comment: well usually we use something like divs to wrap each element to have more access and to help with the jquery and css (both ways you get new line). Without divs all functionality needs to be done by considering the whole html as a string as you have done. 

for instance your filter function can be done much easier if you use divs
`$('#screenlist div').filter(function(v){  })`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Could you wrap your appended content in span tags?

```js
$('.delete_icon').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().hide('slow');
});
```

```css
#screenlist span {
  display: flex;
}

.delete_icon {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="screenlist">
    <span>www.sampleurl.com<span class="delete_icon">x</span></span>
    <span>www.sampleurl.com<span class="delete_icon">x</span></span>
    <span>www.sampleurl.com<span class="delete_icon">x</span></span>
    <span>www.sampleurl.com<span class="delete_icon">x</span></span>
    <span>www.sampleurl.com<span class="delete_icon">x</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `hide('slow')` can't be used since that is a part of jquery ui not jquery

Comment: The questions asks how to `remove`, not `hide`.  They're quite different if the DOM is getting scraped at some later time to do something useful with the data.

Comment: @QZ Support Remove can mean a lot of things to someone. .remove would be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I attach a click event to that span element that will be dynamic on every element created and that when clicked the complete row is deleted?

The problem is your assumption of what an `element` is, and in the context of your example, it more closely represents a [list of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325794), which means you have to treat it as such and that breaks any self (`this`) or `parent` or sibling type relative logic which would usually be used to tackle the problem.

In this case, some would shim in a unique id for each element e.g.

**Works, not recommended**

```
<span id='link_001'>www.sampleurl.com</span>
  <span class="delete_icon" onclick="document.getElementById('link_001').remove()"/></br>
```

But you'll still have a lingering `X` delete icon afterward.

You need to either have the URL and the `X` delete icon as part of the same higher element so that you can just blindly remove its `parent`, or some unique identifier which gives the `X` information about which URL to delete and then also code the `X` to remove itself.

**Recommended**

The recommended approach wraps each URL in an unordered list (`ul`).  The `ul` is only provided as an example because list items (`li`) serve as popular containers for these types of tasks.  That said, a `span` or `div` should work fine in place of `li` if `ul/li` is not desired.

Since the `X` is part of the same parent element (`li`), it can quickly find it and remove it sanely without trying to parse an array of text data.

```
<ul>
<li>http://stackoverflow.com <span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="remove(this)">x</span></li>
<li>http://askubuntu.com <span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="remove(this)">x</span></li>
</ul>

<script>
function remove(o) {
   o.parentElement.remove();
}
</script>
```

Although the question specifically asks how to do this with jQuery, the above pure JavaScript examples offer no additional code.  If you prefer you can always wrap `$(this)` and call `onclick="$(this).parent.remove()"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are unable to wrap tags around your url's here is a possible solution I jerry rigged together from my own storage methods and the [question and answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318887/replace-word-in-p-in-div-using-jquery)

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/ku0t7mey/13/

**edit**

Definitely read this guys answer for [a much more simplified solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39303304/3377049) than my below example.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete_icon', function() {
    var toDelete = $(this).attr('stringStorage');
    function replaceNodeText() {
      if (this.nodeType === 3) {
          this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(replaceNodeText.find, replaceNodeText.replace);
      } else {
          $(this).contents().each(replaceNodeText);
      }
    }
    replaceNodeText.find = toDelete;
    replaceNodeText.replace = "";
    $("#screenlist").contents().each(replaceNodeText);
    $(this).next('br').remove();
    $(this).remove();
});



$(document).on('click', '.appenderator', function() {
  var i = $('#screenlist').attr('ignorethis');
  var url = 'www.sampleurl' + i + '.com';
  $('#screenlist').append(url + '<span class="delete_icon" stringStorage="' + url + '">x</span><br>');
  var iPlusOne = parseInt(i) + 1;
  $('#screenlist').attr('ignorethis', iPlusOne);
});
```

```css
.delete_icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.delete_icon:hover { background-color: orange; }

br {
  line-height: 22px;
}

.appenderator {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 2px 8px 2px 8px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: white;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.appenderator:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: hsla(180, 20%, 50%, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="screenlist" ignorethis="4">
www.sampleurl1.com<span class="delete_icon" stringStorage="www.sampleurl1.com">x</span><br>
www.sampleurl2.com<span class="delete_icon" stringStorage="www.sampleurl2.com">x</span><br>
www.sampleurl3.com<span class="delete_icon" stringStorage="www.sampleurl3.com">x</span><br>
</div>

<div class="appenderator">appenderator</div>
```

What it does is store your url into a custom attribute in the delete_icon span you append. When you go to delete the line it gets the string from that attribute, searches for it in `#screenlist`, removes it as well as `.remove`s the `.delete_icon` span itself plus the trailing `<br>` tag.